# the best way to conduct fft using GPU accelaration with cuda

Tags: python, cuda, cufft

In python, what is the best to run fft using cuda gpu computation?
I am using pyfftw to accelerate the `fftn`, which is about 5x faster than `numpy.fftn`.
I want to use `pycuda` to accelerate the fft. I know there is a library called `pyculib`, but I always failed to install it using `conda install pyculib`.
Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use pycuda to accelerate the fft

You can't. PyCUDA has no built-in FFT support of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this isn't too late of answer, but I also needed a FFT Library that worked will with CUDA without having to programme it myself.

I was using the [PyFFT Library](https://pythonhosted.org/pyfft/) which I think is deprecated but should be able to be easily installed via Pip (e.g. `pip install pyfft`) which I much prefer over anaconda. You could also try [Reikna](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/), which I have found very useful if you are doing Spectrograms as well.

Hope this helps a bit! I hope talonmies was too off-putting :)